# How to use ngb-carousel in Angular 7 app?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, carousel, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to add a carousel to my Angular 7 app.
Instead of using the Bootstrap 4 carousel, I was advised to use the ng-bootstrap carousel instead - found [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples)

I ran `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`, and added the code advised in this article. As seen below:

```html
    <ngb-carousel *ngIf="images">
        <ng-template ngbSlide>
            <img [src]="images[0]" alt="Random first slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>First slide label</h3>
                <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template ngbSlide>
            <img [src]="images[1]" alt="Random second slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template ngbSlide>
            <img [src]="images[2]" alt="Random third slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Third slide label</h3>
                <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-carousel>
```

TS:

```js
    images = [1, 2, 3].map(() => https://picsum.photos/900/500?random&t=${Math.random()});
```

Also, I've added in `import` in `app.module.ts`:

```js
    import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

    imports: [
        NgbModule
    ],
```

I installed `bootstrap` using npm & added it to the `styles` section of my `angular.json` file.

Now, the below carousel is appearing:

[image]
As you can see, the text is not centered & only one arrow is appearing on the image.
When I inspect the element, this is where the other arrow is located:

[image]

If I open the console, & the screen is made smaller, both arrows appear:

[image]

It appears that the arrows & text are shifted left when the screen is made smaller. Can someone please point out how to get this appearing correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Are there any errors on the console?

Comment: HI @wentjun, no there are no errors appearing in console.

Comment: have you imported the NgbModule in the @NgModule import ?

Comment: In that case, I think it is your CSS then. Have you actually include the styles from the default boostrap package?

Comment: Ok , you are missing the bootstrap css , i advise you to install via npm and add it in the angular.json

Answer (score 2):

You probably didn't add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />` to the index.html

You should [end up with something like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wyfcfs?file=app/carousel-config.ts).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I installed bootstrap via npm & added it to `styles` inside my `angular.json` & a carousel is now appearing. But, with the HTML I have above the carousel is appearing incorrectly. Only the left hand side nav button is displayed & the image is cut off

Comment: Can you fork my stackblitz, make the changes which can reproduce your issue?

Comment: I have done so, & am still getting the same issue. The console appears to "push" the arrows & text to the left

Comment: Also, when I open your stackblitz in a browser like so: [here](https://angular-wyfcfs-wcsbkm.stackblitz.io/) the same issue is occuring.

Comment: `max-width:100%` on the image would fix that for you... stackBlitz updated with it also.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue, my solution may not be valid in all of the cases but in my case all of the images were in the square form, So what I did to make that work is:

```
<ngb-carousel style="width: 350px; height: 350px; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px">
        <ng-template ngbSlide>
                <img [src]="image_path" alt="Random first slide" style="width: 350px; height: 350px; ">
        </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

This code made my arrows on the correct postion. And what I did to make my arrows more visible is by making my custom arrows using the given css

```
.carousel-control-prev-icon{
     background-image: url('https://apufpel.com.br/assets/img/seta_prim.png')
}
.carousel-control-next-icon{
     background-image: url('https://apufpel.com.br/assets/img/seta_ult.png')
}
```